# How to access file start with period '.' in shell

Tags: linux, shell

Special characters can be distinguished using backslash character \ . However, I want to treat full period as a normal character to operate on hidden folders. For example:

`ls -lh .`

It will list the current directory. However, I want to list all the hidden folders. I want it to be usable with `du -h`, so I know the disk space the hidden folders consumed.

Comment: du -h will report on the usage of hidden files.  Files with names beginning with '.' are not hidden to du.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Files and directories whose names start with `.` are "hidden" only in the sense that (a) `ls` ignores them by default and (b) wildcard expansion excludes them.  In both cases, you can see dot files if you refer to them explicitly.  `*` expands to all non-dot files; `.*` expands to all dot files.

(Other tools and commands may also treat them as hidden; for example, GUI file managers like Nautilus typically don't show dot files by default, but there's often an option to show them.)

`ls -a` overrides the special treatment of files whose names start with `.`.  `ls -A` lists "hidden" files and folders, but excludes `.` (this directory) and `..` (the parent directory); some versions of `ls` might not support `-A`.

The `du` command, as far as I know, doesn't treat dot files as hidden.  `du -h` should show the entire directory tree starting at the current directory.  (Try it in a small directory tree to make sure yours behaves this way.)

**EDIT :**

I've confirmed that at least the GNU coreutils version of `du` doesn't treat files or directories whose names start with `.` specially; nothing is hidden.

For example, this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p .dot/.dot .dot/nodot nodot/.dot nodot/nodot
du -h
```

produces this output on my system (the specific numbers depend on the nature of the file system, and are irrelevant to the current discussion):

```
4.0K    ./.dot/.dot
4.0K    ./.dot/nodot
12K     ./.dot
4.0K    ./nodot/.dot
4.0K    ./nodot/nodot
12K     ./nodot
32K     .
```

Does that meet your requirements?  If not, can you explain more clearly just what you're looking for?  Do you want to list *all* directories, whether their names begin with `.` or not?  Do you want to list only "hidden" directories?  What output would you like for the directory structure created by the above script?

Comment: I want to count the size of hidden directories only. I tried `du -h | grep .*`, and seemed to filter out other files/directories except hidden ones. However the output included file content as well.

Comment: `grep .*` is a no-op (it matches every line containing zero or more characters). As for the behavior of `du`, I'll try to take a look at it later today.

Comment: "I want to count the size of hidden directories only."  What about hidden directories under non-hidden directories (`foo/.bar`)?  What about hidden vs. non-hidden files under hidden directories?  In any case, I know of no straightforward way to do what you're trying to do.  `du` simply ignores the distinction between hidden and non-hidden directories; it's the same problem as, for example, counting only directories whose names start with 'X'.  A customized tool might be the best solution.  You could modify the GNU Coreutils version of `du`.  Knowing *why* you want to do this might also help.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong place for this question, but it's simple enough:

`ls -lhd .*`

Comment: Well you can consider part of shell scripting, so it won't be invalid. Anyway, is there other way rather than putting the asterisk `*`? I want it to be usable with `du -h`

Answer (score 2):

what about `ls -lh .*` ? (This may answer you question)